# Rails3 Module Help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

So I'm currently trying to upgrade from 2.3 -> 3, and I'm running into an issue.  In rails 2.3 I had a module that was comprised of autocomplete methods.  So on key press an ajax request would be sent to the corresponding message.  For example:

/grants/auto_complete_for_grant_name

```
module AutoComplete

 def auto_complete_for_grant_name
  name = params[:grant][:name].downcase  
  @grants = Grant.find(:all, :limit => 10, :conditions => "name like '%"+name+"%'")
  render :partial => 'global/grants' 
 end
end
```

Once I upgraded to rails3 this is broken.  I have included:

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

in my application.rb, and:

```
include AutoComplete
```

in my application controller.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Edit:
(Firebug output): Failed to load source for: http://localhost:3000/grants/auto_complete_for_grant_name

Comment: Do you have any error messages? "this is broken" is a little too vague to debug well. More information about what specifically is broken would help a lot.

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Failed to load source for: http://localhost:3000/grants/auto_complete_for_grant_name

Answer (score 1):

`autocomplete_for_grant_name` and `auto_complete_for_grant_name` spell *autocomplete* differently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to answer your actual question but I feel it's worth pointing out that `:conditions => "name like '%"+name+"%'"` is a **huge** mistake. This is prone to SQL injection attacks.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions

Comment: yes i've noticed this when the user inserts a single quotation

Comment: It's also not an indexable query, security concerns aside, so it'll be nice and slow once you get to real data.